# cinnamon-settings not working

Tags: debian, cinnamon

cinnamon-settings is not working. I'm not sure, but I think it stopped working after the installation of hplib (https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip).

I'm using:

- Cinnamon 3.2.7
- Debian 9.8
- Python 2.7.13 (just in case)

  Here's the output of cinnamon-settings:

  ```
     $ cinnamon-settings

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line 43, in <module>
      modules = map(__import__, mod_files)
    File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_backgrounds.py", line 5, in <module>
      import imtools
    File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/imtools.py", line 622, in <module>
       if Image.VERSION == '1.1.7':
      AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VERSION'
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, and I found out a bit more about the problem.
It is related to an update of python-pillow. It breaks the imtools.py file.

I found the fix here - https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/8495